# ClassNotFoundException : fuseki-server.jar

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, jena, fuseki

I am attempting to perform SPARQL update queries using fuseki-server.jar with the following code:

```
UpdateRequest ur = UpdateFactory.create();
ur.add(update);
UpdateProcessRemote r = new UpdateProcessRemote(ur,address);
r.execute();
```

However, it is failing with the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [QualityAssessment] in context with path [/GTQuality] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateProcessRemote
```

Initial reaction is that it is a classpath problem but fuseki-server.jar is both included in the build path and in WEB-INF/lib so I'm a bit stuck. The exact same code works perfectly as a standalone Java project.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how you are running this code? It compiles so clearly you have the right libraries.

Comment: I use a SPIN reasoner and so I thought I'd be constrained to ARQ2.8.7. Upgrading to 2.9.4 has fixed the problem (and SPIN still works!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked elsewhere: [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/19840/jenasparqlmodifyupdateprocessremote-class-not-found](https://web.archive.org/web/20130924132439/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/19840/jenasparqlmodifyupdateprocessremote-class-not-found)

If it works standalone, and not elsewhere, then it's a setup problem.

fuseki-server.jar for 0.2.5 does contain UpdateProcessRemote:

unzip -v fuseki-server.jar | grep UpdateProcessRemote.class ==>

```
1498  Defl:N      739  51% 2012-10-20 17:05 1517e336  com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/modify/UpdateProcessRemote.class
```

Look for other (old) copies of ARQ.